# PAC Manager localhost configuration

Tags: ssh, pac-manager

I have installed pac manager to open multiple ssh sessions of my local machine.

I have created a SSH session and plugged in my ipaddress, username and password but when I click connect "button", it tries to connect but I don'get any results.

Comment: Please add, What distribution you are using, If you have installed and enabled ssh, the output of `sudo netstat -tlnp | grep ssh` Cheers.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu 14.02 and I see the ssh process running when I execute the commands.

Comment: Can you add the output of the netstat command to your question, it will at least show what its listening on.